# snail in the well javascript challenge

Tags: javascript, loops

This is my first question on stack overflow although this question had been answered before I didn't get enough details to understand why the code was written that way and I didn't just want to copy and paste the solution without understanding it.

The snail climbs 7 feet each day and slips back 2 feet each night, How many days will it take the snail to get out of a well with the given depth?
**Sample Input**
31
**Sample Output**
6
this is was what i wrote but it didn't work

```
function main() {
var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
//your code goes here
let climb = 0, days = 0;
   for(climb + 7; climb < depth; days++){
       climb += 2;
       console.log(days);
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? There is code missing so you should get a syntax error. Is that what you are talking about? However, on obvious issue is that you never *subtract* values anywhere, so how do you account for the "slipping back" part?

Comment: So what *have* you found online and what *specifically* do you not understand about that? How have you debugged your code so far (looks like there are some syntax errors present so start by fixing those). Take it one step at a time. You can also try to write pseudo code first and then convert that to a concrete implementation.

Comment: the solution is not to use a loop at all, code shouldn't be treated like real life, i.e you don't have to make a snail and implement physics of it to resolve a result, code can do basic math.. `console.log(depth / 5)`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, depth/5 is an oversimplification. E.g in the initial depth is 6 or 7, days to escape = 1, not 1 and 2/5th ,or 2 days. It can be done with math, just not quite simple math

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
  var depth = parseInt(readline(), 10);
  var day = 0;
  for(let climb = 0; climb <= depth;) {
      day +=1;
      climb += 7;
      if(climb >= depth) {
          break;
      }
      climb -= 2;
  }
  console.log(day);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take input and write this
`var day= Math.ceil((depth-2)/5);`
and output that!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* day --> 7++
night --> 2-- */
var day = 0;
var total = 0;
var input = 41;
 while (input>total){
     day++;
     total+=7;
   if (total>=input){
       console.log(day);
       break;
   }
   total = total -2
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. Dumping code without an explanation is rarely helpful.

Comment: i will keep this in mind form the next time thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, no need to loop. Just work out the math of the problem an use that.

```js
function snailCalc (depth, dailyGain, nightlyLoss) {
  var days = 1;
  var netGain = dailyGain-nightlyLoss;
  if(depth > dailyGain ) {   
    //Basic calc based on net gain taking the first day into account
    days = (depth-dailyGain)/netGain;
    //Add the fist day
    days += 1;
    //We want whole days so use Mathc.ceil
    days = Math.ceil(days)
    //Or we could do all that in one line
    //days = Math.ceil(((depth-dailyGain)/netGain) + 1);
  }
  return days;
}

const gain = 7;
const loss = 2

for(var d = 1; d < 31; d++)
{
  console.log(`Depth: ${d}, Days: ${snailCalc(d, gain, loss)}` )
}
```

```html
Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function main() {
    var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    console.log(Math.round(depth / 5))
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Dumping the code without an explanation is rarely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
function main() {
    var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    //your code goes here
    var days=1;
    var level =0;
    for(level =0;level<depth;days++){
        level+=7
        if(level<depth){
            level-=2;
        } else{
            break ;
        }
        
    }console.log(days)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I had the same trouble a couple days ago and we find the error is that using js you need to reset the variable where you sum the result before evaluate again if the distance the snail climbed that day is greater than the depth to end the clycle.

```
depth = 31;
let days = 0;
let climb = 0;

while(climb < depth){
    let result = climb + 7;
    if(result  >= depth){ 
        days++;
        break;
    }
    climb = result - 2;
    days++;
    //console.log("climb ",climb);

}

console.log(days);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the function input and test the snipet:

[for more you can run code and check result ↗](https://code.sololearn.com/cO9b9uEMh58s)

Eg : main(128) // 26

```js
function main(input) {
  let depth = input

  let climbsUp = 7
  let slipsBack = 2
  let distance = climbsUp - slipsBack
  let days = 0;
  let rDepth = Math.round(depth / distance)

  for (let i = 0; i < rDepth; i++) {
    distance = distance + 5
    days = ++days
    if (days === 6) {
      console.log('days will it take the snail to get out of a well : ' + rDepth)
    } else {
      console.log('days will it take the snail to get out of a well : ' + rDepth)
      break;
    }

  }
}

main(42);
main(128);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).